# How can I open a javascript Window with a webpage in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I would like to create a link for a website, and after I clicked for the link, I want to open the page in a javascript popup window.
I created a function for this, but unfortunately I get this message in chrome console:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"
```

My script looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name filmkodiframe 
// @namespace  http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu
// @description Nézd meg a filmjeidet egyszerűbben filmespolcon!
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
//  @match      *://*.online-filmespolc.net/*

// ==/UserScript==

// Finnaly attach it into the DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<a target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;hover:text-decoration:none;" title="A filmkód oldal megnyitása" class="lightview" onclick="myFunction()" id="myFrame" name="myFrame">Film</a>').appendTo('#password');
        function myFunction() {
             window.open("http://filmkod.uw.hu/index.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
        }
});
```

I don't get it why doesn't work, because I use document ready, and the javascript under of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a jQuery event handler and remove the inline `onclick`

```
$('<a target="_blank"...</a>').click(myFunction).appendTo('#password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the myFunction out of the document.ready function into the global namespace and it will work, like this:

```
window.newNamespace = {};
newNamespace.myFunction = function() {
    window.open("http://filmkod.uw.hu/index.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<a target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;color:blue;hover:text-decoration:none;" title="A filmkód oldal megnyitása" class="lightview" onclick="newNamespace.myFunction()" id="myFrame" name="myFrame">Film</a>').appendTo('#password');
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined again :(

Comment: Do you have a namespace wrapping all that code? myFunction needs to be accessible from the global namespace in order to use it the way you want, or you need to explicitly put it into your own namespace and reference it there

Comment: I tryed change the function name, but nothing happend.

Comment: Thanks, But I have  answer by @charlietfl